# Why does my script fails on autostart but works fine when executed manually?

Tags: python

I am using a python script to send a json to an arduino to controll led intensity by pwm. The script parses a csv file to find the current led instensity to set up. The script looks like that:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

#Script for serial communication with arduino-based board.
#Sends an output state on a preset pin.

import serial
from datetime import datetime, date, time
from time import sleep
import json
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
 ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1) #TODO: Fix hardcode
 lightSchedule1 = pd.read_csv("/home/pi/vivarium-controller-production/vivarium-controller/LightSchedule1.dat", sep = "\t", names = ("Hour", "Intensity"))
 lightSchedule2 = pd.read_csv("/home/pi/vivarium-controller-production/vivarium-controller/LightSchedule2.dat", sep = "\t", names = ("Hour", "Intensity"))
 pin1 = 5
 pwm1 = 0
 pin2 = 6
 pwm2 = 0
 while True:
  currentTime = datetime.now().time()
  ser.flush()
  currentParams1 = lightSchedule1[lightSchedule1["Hour"] == datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")]
  currentParams2 = lightSchedule2[lightSchedule2["Hour"] == datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")]
  pwm1 = int(currentParams1["Intensity"].iloc[0])
  pwm2 = int(currentParams2["Intensity"].iloc[0])
  msgDict = {
   "Light1": [pin1, pwm1],
   "Light2": [pin2, pwm2],
  }
  msgToSend = json.dumps(msgDict)
  ser.write(msgToSend.encode('ascii'))
  sleep(0.1)
  incoming = ser.readline().decode("utf-8")
  #print (incoming)
  sleep(0.05)
  #ser.write(bytes(currentTime.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), 'utf-8'))
  #ser.write(bytes("\n", 'utf-8')) #TODO: This is not elegant
```

Now, this works ok when executed from terminal, even using `sudo`. However, since adding pandas to parse, when trying to add the script to autostart, the following error occurs (either using `/etc/rc.local`, as well as `systemctl`)

```
Dec 05 20:15:55 raspberrypi-zero-noir systemd[1]: Started TimerSwitch.
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]: StopIteration
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/encodings/iso8859_2.py", line 15, in decode
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]:     return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]: SystemError: <built-in function charmap_decode> returned a result with an error set
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]: SystemError: decoding with 'iso8859-2' codec failed (SystemError: <built-in function charmap_decode> returned a result with an error set)
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/encodings/iso8859_2.py", line 15, in decode
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]:     return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]: SystemError: <built-in function charmap_decode> returned a result with an error set
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]:   File "/home/pi/vivarium-controller-production/vivarium-controller/timer_switch.py", line 14, in <module>
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]:     lightSchedule1 = pd.read_csv("/home/pi/vivarium-controller-production/vivarium-controller/LightSchedule1.dat", sep = "\t", names = ("Hour", "Intensity"))
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]:     return func(*args, **kwargs)
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 586, in read_csv
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]:     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 488, in _read
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]:     return parser.read(nrows)
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1047, in read
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]:     index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py", line 224, in read
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]:     chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
Dec 05 20:16:05 raspberrypi-zero-noir python3[444]: SystemError: decoding with 'iso8859-2' codec failed (SystemError: <built-in function charmap_decode> returned a result with an error set)
Dec 05 20:16:06 raspberrypi-zero-noir systemd[1]: timerswitch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 05 20:16:06 raspberrypi-zero-noir systemd[1]: timerswitch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The

```
/etc/systemd/system/timerswitch.service
```

is :

```
[Unit]
Description=TimerSwitch
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Typie=idle
User=pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/vivarium-controller-production/vivarium-controller/timer_switch.py
Restart=always
RestartSec=120

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: AFAIK, `rc.local` is deprecated. Did the script run OK under `systemd` control **before** you added Pandas? Have you tried starting it under a `crontab`?

Comment: It seems that using ```crontab``` does not work either.

Comment: Does the addition of Pandas affect the outcome?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it works fine

Comment: You're not much help here, so I'll step aside. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry to dissapoint you, but I'm stuck. The script works as is when run from terminal, and only this specific pandas method causes the failure when added to autostart. Without it, it also autostarts well.

Comment: Perhaps then your interactive shell's PATH has something in it that is missing when you run it from `systemd`?

Comment: That's right! I thought about it at first, but both ```echo $PATH``` and ```sudo echo $PATH``` gave the same output. Turns out when I added ```echo $PATH > /home/pi/log``` to crontab, it printed just ```/usr/bin:/bin``` instead of ```/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games```. I'll try and fix it now. Thanks!

Comment: I think you are ["barking up the wrong tree"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Barking+Up+the+Wrong+Tree) asking your question here. [U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions) is probably a better choice, but read [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347873/set-path-for-a-systemd-unit) before posting a question there. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) is another good alternative.